# HMCM vs Viterbi algorithm for calculating most likely path of an HMM

Tags: hidden-markov-model, markov-chain

My expertise in machine learning and statistics is probably at a sophomore level. But anyway, my question is this:

Given a Hidden Markov Model returned over a sequence of events with some states, how do you find the most likely path over the states given only the information to create this HMM?

There are 2 things I've learned about in my research: the Viterbi Algorithm and Markov Chain Monte Carlo. As far as I can tell, the Viterbi algorithm is an analytical approach applying some math over the transition matrix of the HMM to find the most likely sequence of future states. And a MCMC is an empirical approach using a stochastic method over the transition matrix to find the most likely path over the states.

I'm wondering if the previous paragraph I wrote is correct. And, if paragraph is correct, in what situations would I use one method over the other?

Comment: MCMC doesn't just find the most likely path. It can give a great deal of information about probabilities of any paths and any states. It *could* be used to find the most likely path, but (to take a simpler situation) that's like saying "the purpose of simulating from a distribution is to identify its mode".

Answer (score 1):

Given an HMM $(X_i, Y_i)$ where $X_i$ are the hidden states and $Y_i$ are the observables, the Viterbi algorithm finds the most likely sequence of hidden states $X_{1:n}$ given the sequence of observables $Y_{1:n}$, namely it finds the sequence $X_{1:n}$ which maximizes the conditional distribution $P(\{X_i\}|\{Y_i\}, \theta)$ where $\theta$ is the set of parameters defining the model. In particular, the Viterbi algorithm provides a pointwise estimate in that it requires knowledge of the model parameters $\theta$ (usually estimated from the data as ${\hat \theta}$, for example using the EM algorithm, or Baum-Welch for HMM) and in that it provides a single best estimate for the most likely state rather some posterior distribution. The Viterbi algorithm is fast because the full joint probability distribution of an HMM factorized into a tree structure, therefore the maximization problem can be cast in an efficient dynamic programming form comprising two phases:

1. a forward pass, maximizing the forward probabilities $P(X_{1:i}, Y_{1:i}|\theta)$ and keeping track of the maximizing states for all possible paths;
2. a backward tracking pass, reconstructing the maximizing sequence of states tracing back from $n$ to $1$.

MCMC offers a machinery to move away from a pointwise estimate (*frequentist*) approach as given above and make inference in an HMM in a Bayesian way, providing instead estimates for for the posterior distributions of all variables in the model, including the set of parameter $\theta$. Typically this is done by introducing priors and defining conditional probabilities for all parameters, and then running a Gibbs sampler.

Details can be easily found around the web, see for example [this](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/rabiner.pdf) nice tutorial from Rabiner and [this](http://ba.stat.cmu.edu/journal/2008/vol03/issue04/ryden.pdf) recent article from Rydén comparing EM and MCMC approaches for HMM.